# Send a div as attachment in mail in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having a php page which is a dynamically generated ticket page and I've added a button to print the ticket content. Here is an example

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="ticket-div">
    <table><?php here goes the contents of ticket ?></table>
   </div>
   <button>Print this ticket</button>
    <button>Email Ticket</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

And I wonder how to specify only the div contents in mail function that I use.

```
<?
if(($Content = file_get_contents("ticket.php")) === false) {
    $Content = "";
}

$Headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$Headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$Headers .= "From: ".$FromName." <".$FromEmail.">\n";
$Headers .= "Reply-To: ".$ReplyTo."\n";
$Headers .= "X-Sender: <".$FromEmail.">\n";
$Headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n"; 
$Headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; 
$Headers .= "Return-Path: <".$FromEmail.">\n";  

if(mail($ToEmail, $Subject, $Content, $Headers) == false) {
    //Error
}
```

?>

what I want is , just attach the contents of div "ticket-div" in an email so that the customer can download it from his mail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm able to print that div using javascript.

Comment: What's your budget for this project?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy what that matters?

Comment: Well, you've come here to ask us to do work for you. There's no attempts (from what I can see) to create this yourself. So naturally I can assume you're looking for us to do your work - which is surely not what this site is for. Therefore, I'm wondering what you're willing to pay to have someone create this for you, because you'd do well on http://guru.com

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: sorry all, see the edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript for this purpose and specify the headers.use the code below

```
        <?php
    if($_GET['email']){
         $to   = "xyz@xyz.com"; // Write the email here
          $from = 'info@phpgang.com'; // Write your email here

          $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
          $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
          $headers .= "CC: info@sitename.com\r\n";
          $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $message = "
          <div id='ticket-div'>
            <table>here is the content of the ticket</table>
           </div>

        ";
           mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
echo  $message = "
          <div id='ticket-div'>
            <table>here is the content of the ticket</table>
           </div>

        ";
        ?>

        <button onclick='window.print();'>Print this ticket</button>
    <form action='url to this file.php' method='POST'>
         <input type='submit' name='email' id='button'>Email Ticket</button>
    </form>
```

The code above can take some time but it will deliver your mail for sure. 
I made a script of what you wanted , download it from this url `wpbrisk.com/download/email/email/email.zip`. Or you can try the demo out by visiting this url

```
http://wpbrisk.com/download/email/email/index.php?email_addr=YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE
```

I was working for this script the whole eve and will be writing an article on my site http://hangupin.com . Be sure to read it
Hope this helps you

Comment: how can I print this mail? I just need only the div contents  as attachment(pdf) in email.

Comment: but how can that be an attachment and downloaded?

Comment: I didn't completely understood what you are saying but looks like that you want to give the user to print the ticket and mail the ticket to his email. Am i right?

Comment: yes but either print or mail.Print is working, I need to send this div as pdf in a mail, so that the user can download the attachment.

Comment: @Riyaz Made a script for you and a demo too. Have a look at my answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68026/discussion-between-hudixt-and-riyaz).